# Retain form inputs upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, textarea

i'm programming in web using php, and javascript , and this is a general question i'd like to ask,  normally upon page refresh everything that is in a textarea or input gets deleted;

Is there a way to retain the user inputs, typed characters or checked checkboxes?without saving into session? or do i really need to save it? Thank you!

(i'm not talking about form submit that leads to reload, but just plain typing into textarea and then pressing the refresh button.)

Comment: Cookies or Local Storage are your best bet.

Comment: can you give me a demo on how to do this?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial on it on [Toasted Digital](http://www.toasteddigital.com/blog/html5-jquery-localstorage-forms.html).